# Using wildcards in find and replace to delete a long string

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I'm looking to replace all instances of a changing string of characters within a document. Here is an example of the string:

```
[[npr_B6G8879JASKLDF378SJKDAS9__06BF5A]]
```

The number/letter string following `[[npr_` changes every time, but always closes with `]]`

Normally, I would use `\[*\]` to replace all of this, however this document also has items within `[[` `]]` that I *do not* want to delete. None of these bracketed items contain `npr`, however.

I've tried `\<[[npr>*\]`, but this is not a valid range.

Any ideas would be *very* appreciated!

Comment: `this document also has items within [[ ]] that I do not want to delete. None of these bracketed items contain bsi, however.` - I do not understand that part. Do you want to keep `bsi` under all circumstances or do you want to delete the content of all `[[ ]]`-strings that start with `bsi_`, including the `bsi_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALL special characters need to be escaped (including all `]` and `[`), so your correct find expression is:

`\[\[npr_*\]\]`